# Why is the "crescent moon and star" being used as the symbol of Islam by some Muslims?

Tags: history, islamic-basis, symbolism

Is [star and crescent](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_and_crescent) a symbol of Islam?

Is it a tradition or is it mentioned in the Qur'an?

Comment: Dan, off-topic. whats is the meaning of the symbol in your profile?

Comment: @HaLaBi It is the symbol of a 32nd degree Scottish Rite mason.  Feel free to email me if you have more questions about it or other masonic symbols as I do not think it belongs in this SE.  However I am starting another SE specifically for questions like this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41173/freemasonry

Comment: This question is about Muslims, not Islam, and so is off-topic for this site. Feel free to follow up in chat.

Comment: @ashes999 sorry, I didn't know that is was specific to some Muslims until Ahmed's answer.

Comment: @DanAndrews I figured; that's why I directed you to chat. We get all kinds of questions like this :)

Comment: Dan, I would love to chat with you. I have like million questions in mind.

Comment: @ashes999: *This question is about Muslims, not Islam, and so is off-topic for this site.*- Disagreed for the part - *Is it a tradition or is it mentioned in the Qur'an?* He is asking if it is Islamic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Islam has no symbols. Quran doesn't suggest or order to use any symbol, but doesn't prohibit as well.

The story behind the reason why some people use the crescent moon as a symbol is explained in the passage below.

> The crescent moon and star symbol actually pre-dates Islam by several thousand years. Information on the origins of the symbol are difficult to ascertain, but most sources agree that these ancient celestial symbols were in use by the peoples of Central Asia and Siberia in their worship of sun, moon, and sky gods. There are also reports that the crescent moon and star were used to represent the Carthaginian goddess Tanit or the Greek goddess Diana.
>
> The city of Byzantium (later known as Constantinople and Istanbul) adopted the crescent moon as its symbol. According to some reports, they chose it in honor of the goddess Diana. Others indicate that it dates back to a battle in which the Romans defeated the Goths on the first day of a lunar month. In any event, the crescent moon was featured on the city's flag even before the birth of Christ.
>
> **The early Muslim community did not really have a symbol. During the time of the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him), Islamic armies and caravans flew simple solid-colored flags (generally black, green, or white) for identification purposes. In later generations, the Muslim leaders continued to use a simple black, white, or green flag with no markings, writing, or symbolism on it.**
>
> It wasn't until the Ottoman Empire that the crescent moon and star became affiliated with the Muslim world. When the Turks conquered Constantinople (Istanbul) in 1453, they adopted the city's existing flag and symbol. Legend holds that the founder of the Ottoman Empire, Osman, had a dream in which the crescent moon stretched from one end of the earth to the other. Taking this as a good omen, he chose to keep the crescent and make it the symbol of his dynasty. There is speculation that the five points on the star represent the five pillars of Islam, but this is pure conjecture. The five points were not standard on the Ottoman flags, and as you will see on the following page, it is still not standard on flags used in the Muslim world today.
>
> For hundreds of years, the Ottoman Empire ruled over the Muslim world. After centuries of battle with Christian Europe, it is understandable how the symbols of this empire became linked in people's minds with the faith of Islam as a whole.
>
> Based on this history, many Muslims reject using the crescent moon as a symbol of Islam. The faith of Islam has historically had no symbol, and many refuse to accept what is essentially an ancient pagan icon. It is certainly not in uniform use among Muslims.
>
> (Source: http://islam.about.com/od/history/a/crescent_moon.htm)

Answer (score -3):

Actually the belief in Islam states that the represents:
The crescent represents progress and the five pointed star, light and knowledge. The moon is the appointed sign of times, seasons, fast and feast, and governs the Islamic calendar.

Comment: Claims about what it represents in Islam should be supported with references.

Answer (score -5):

Because Moon symbolizes Isa Ruh Allah while the stars symbolizes Mommins.

> The Sun (of surface temperature of 5778 K) and the Moon (of orbital
>   period of 27 days) are never going to join with each other because the
>   Sun and Moon have already joined 355 years ago in India!
>
> ---
>
> According to Prophet Muhammad, Isa Ruh Allah was supposed to wear two
>   garments. Therefore, the first garment of Isa Ruh Allah was the
>   physical body of Devchandra Mehta himself. However, upon leaving his
>   first garment, Isa Ruh Allah had to wear his second and final garment
>   by entering into the physical body of Meher Raj Thakur! And this is
>   how the Sun (Mahdi) and the Moon (Isa) would join together!

http://sanandhonline.blogspot.com/2013/12/the-sun-and-moon-are-joined.html

Comment: That sounds like hogwash invented by that blogger, no references to any sources.